# Where are my environment variables set on Vista32?

Tags: windows-vista, system, environment-variables

By following:

`Start -> Computer -> Right Click -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Advanced -> Environment Variables`

I find `User variables for brianjd` (which includes `TMP` and `TEMP`) and `System Variables` (which includes, `Path`, `USERNAME`, etc.). I would expect these variables to be set in `C:\AUTOEXEC.BAT` or `C:\CONFIG.SYS`. Instead, I find `REM Dummy file for NTVDM` and `FILES=40` in those files.

Q: Where are the files that actually set the environment variables with statements like `SET USERNAME=brianjd`?

Q: When I follow the Windows GUI path above and add the variable name and value `FOO` and `C:\foo` to either `User variables for brianjd` or `System Variables`, what is actually happening? What is Windows writing to where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables are not in a script file like /etc/environment on Linux, for example. Windows stores them in the registry. The keys are "HKCU\Environment" (user variables) and "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" (system-wide variables).

See also the relevant [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682653%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you. I've located them with RegEdit. I have a follow-up question I posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146842/where-is-userprofile-on-vista32). I'm confused why `USERPROFILE` shows up when I `SET` from the command line but it neither shows up using the Windows GUI path above nor RegEdit.