# Where is `USERPROFILE` on Vista32?

Tags: windows-vista, environment-variables

This is a follow-up question to [Where are my environment variables set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146526/where-are-my-environment-variables-set-on-vista32). In that post it's mentioned how one can find environment variables using the Windows GUI or RegEdit. What's strange to me is that `SET` from the command line displays a `USERPROFILE=C:\Users\brianjd` but it doesn't show up using the Windows GUI or RegEdit methods.

Q: Where is `USERPROFILE`? Why does it show up using `SET` but doesn't show up using Windows GUI or RegEdit?

Comment: What do you mean by "where"? Also I think this might be a better fit for http://superuser.com

Comment: @BoltClock: by "where" I mean where will I find `USERPROFILE=C:\Users\brianjd` on my hard drive? How can I get to it and tweak it? In the case of, say, `TEMP`, it's clearly in the registry and I can tweak it from there.

Comment: @BoltClock: I'll wait a bit and then maybe re-post over at superuser?

Comment: Maybe, if this post doesn't get migrated by then.

Comment: Any luck with the comments and answers? Did you repost it at last? (If you could link in that case please)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may find what you need in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\ProfilesDirectory`

Each user has it's own Profile key as well, which stores the ProfileImagePath (and is set to the same value as `%userprofile%`)

It may explain why this is not a environment variable that appears in the GUI.

I don't have any source to confirm that sorry. But I had to use this to repair a broken profile last week.
Hope it helps.

M'vy

Comment: Yes, I see where this is. Instead of `ProfilesDirectory` it was `S-1-5-21...`. What you say make sense. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it is set by winlogon.exe or userinit.exe when you log in. Clearly, the USER* variables have to be set by the system since domain and profile path can change.